# int binarySearch arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, binary

Hi I am obviously still trying to learn java and could not find an answer on the site.

Basically im supposed to add a new private, generic method called binarySearch

The method is supposed to implement the recursive binary search algorithm and it looks for  elements that have the same value for the last name field as the value passed in the searchLastName method parameter.

However, i think i am somewhat correct but i am getting an error on both of the **.get** (Error: cannot find symbol)

```
private static < E extends People > int binarySearch(ArrayList<E> list, int first, int     last, String searchLastName)
{
   int middle;


if(first > last )
    return -1;

middle = (first + last) /2;

if (list.get.compareTo(searchLastName))
{
    return middle;
}
else if (list.get.compareTo(searchLastName) > last)
{
    return binarySearch(list, middle + 1, last, searchLastName);
}

else return binarySearch(list, first, middle - 1, searchLastName );
```

Comment: What is `get` meant to be? Are you using the right syntax for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `get()` is a method so make sure you use`()` also pass the parameter it needs

Comment: I am supposed to call the recursive methods and pass the list which is the array list and pass the lastname

Answer (score 0):

On looking up the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) docs, one can easily out that this class does not contain any such *field* called `get`. The compiler interprets this *field* as the *symbol* which it can't find. In order to correct your code **use the correct method signature**:

```
...
if (list.get (someIndex).compareTo (searchLastName) )
...
```

The some index is the index of the element which you want to access. I wan't you to note that **`something`** is a field and **`something ()`** is a method.

I'm sure that you have some experience with the *arrays of `primitive datatypes`*. Do you remember how to get an element from an array?

```
int a  = someArray [someNumber]; // 0 <= someNumber < someArray.length
```

the [`ArrayList#get ()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) method works in a similar way.